# Sql server 2005 Datatype for Date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to create a table with `DATE` Column.  For that column I am using `DateTime` datatype .

Is there any other datatype or option to display only date without Time. am using Sql Server 2005

Have any format to use?

Otherwise if i use `Datetime` datatype, how can I retrieve in c# with `Update` query.

I use C# code how to retrieve only date

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(("Update tablename set Date = convert(GETDATE(),103) where Name ='" + TextBox1.Text + "' "), con);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C# - query to get only date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085316/in-c-sharp-query-to-get-only-date)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Datetime`. Take a look at [this chart](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005-data-types-reference/).

Comment: No  i am sure There is a option to display only date for Sql Server 2005

Comment: Yes, migrating to SQL Server 2008 or higher.

Comment: @BAP Storing data as a data type and displaying it in the presentation layer are different concepts. For which are you requesting help?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT replace(convert(varchar, getdate(), 111), '/','-' ) -> YYYY-MM-DD
```

Have a look at [How to format datetime & date in Sql Server 2005](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)

Comment: How we can retrieve in c# with INsert query

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you?

Comment: ty for ue reply i want to complete d following query-- SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand(("Update bankopr set Date = convert(GETDATE(),103)   where  Name ='" + TextBox1.Text + "' "), con);

Comment: what is the data type of `Date` field in `bankopr`??

Comment: Then, you don't need to format just simply `set Date =GETDATE()`. Format is only for display purposes!!!

Comment: i Want to diaply only date so

Comment: @BAP: Sorry I am confuse!!! I can't seen any display bit on your question or in comment. I can see only a update command?

Comment: @BAP: Thing here is you haven't clearly mention the issue!!! And you asking for upvote!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server formatting functions with convert functions. Here is the link where you can find all the formatting functions.

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

If you use SQL Server 2008 then only you can use date type.

Answer (score 0):

The DATE data type was not introduced until SQL Server 2008.  As a datatype, it is not part of 2005.  You have to store it as a DATETIME and then use a conversion of some sort to strip the time part off.

Also, SQL Server 2005 is no longer a supported platform.  You should really consider upgrading to a newer platform anyway.

Comment: How we can right query to retrieve in c# with INsert query

Comment: anyhow i have only license for 2005

Answer (score 0):

Follow this pattern,

```
const string updateTable = "UPDATE [dbo].[Tablename]
    SET [Date] = getutcdate()
    WHERE [Name] = @Name;"

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(youConnectionString))
{
    using(var command = new SqlCommand(updateTable, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox1.Text);
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```