# In C# - query to get only date

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

created table with 'DATE' Column ,used 'datetime' Datatype .

How we can code to update only date with c# Update query .

Have any format to display only date?

i use C# code

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(("Update tablename set Date = convert(GETDATE(),103) where Name ='" + TextBox1.Text + "' "), con);
```

Comment: Injection attack, bla bla bla.

Comment: Why store a date as a string in your database? User `DateTime2` instead.

Comment: @GrantWinney m sorry edited. thank you for ur reply in comment

Comment: @Jodrell Wats Injection attack?  its in C# know so.

Comment: @GrantWinney i didnt mention code with c# know so.

Comment: @BAP If I type in `SomeName'; Drop table tablename --` into TextBox1 What will happen?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain i thought dthe whole table will delete

Comment: C# is not immune to injection attacks if you use string manipulation to dynamically build your query. Use a parameterized query, as in my answer.

Comment: yes ty for help me to know abt this..

Comment: RE: What is an injection attack? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev

Answer (score 1):

Follow this pattern,

```
const string updateTable = "UPDATE [dbo].[Tablename]
    SET [Date] = getutcdate()
    WHERE [Name] = @Name;"

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(youConnectionString))
{
    using(var command = new SqlCommand(updateTable, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox1.Text);
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: @BAP the best thanks is an upvote or an accept.

Comment: Am very sorry i have only 5 reputation ,so cant able to vote

Comment: @BAP work at it and your time will come.

Comment: Can u pls tell how to display only date without time

Comment: @BAP you'd have to `SELECT` from the database as a `DateTime` then use something like `yourDateTime.ToString("d")` to convert the value to a string for presentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx